# Is a hyphen or a dash longer?

Tags: hyphenation, colons

Can anyone confirm if the hyphen or dash is longer? Which one is longer than the other and which one is the shorter?

Answer (score -2):

[Let me Google that for you...](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=hyphen%20vs%20dash)

Short answer: a hyphen is shorter than a dash, and has different usage.

If you want a longer answer: [see previously answered question on the matter.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/is-hyphen-really-the-longer-line-instead-of-the-shorter-dash-line?rq=1)

Comment: The convention for responses like this is to flag or close-vote (for those with the ability to). Answering, just to tell them it's google-able and is duplicate, will get nothing but downvotes.

Comment: Fair enough - sorry, I can't help but rebel occasionally ;-)

Comment: Doesn't bother me that you rebel; downvotes don't effect me and it will likely be deleted, anyways. Just advice for you :)